# output operator overloading for queue class C++

Tags: c++, templates, queue, overloading

I am trying to overload the << operator in order to print objects of classes, I tried making a friend function of the operator and then declaring it in below the Queue class, I have not written anything inside the code block here is what I have, it wont compile, it will crash instantly, thanks in advance.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Employee{

protected:
    long empId;
    string empName;
    string email;
public:
        Employee(){}
        Employee(long i, string n){
         empName = n,
         empId =i;
         email = "Unknown";
    }
};

class Student{

protected:
    long stId;
    int year;
    string email;
    string schoolName;
public:
    Student(){}
    Student(long i, int y, string sn){
    stId = i;
    year =y;
    email = "Unknown";
    schoolName=sn;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Queue{
protected:
    vector<T> theQ;
public:
    void Push(T item);
    T pop();
    void ReadAnItem();
    void PrintQ();
    **template<T>** edit
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& is, const Queue<T>& theQ);
};


template<class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Queue<T>& theQ){
        **os << theQ.Print();** Edit
    return os;
}
template<class T>
void Queue<T>::ReadAnItem(){
    T item;
    cout << "Enter the data please: " << endl;
    cin >> item;
    Push(item);
}

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::Push(T item){
    theQ.front() = item;
}

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::PrintQ(){
    cout << "The content of the array is as follows: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i< theQ.size(); i++){
        cout << theQ[i] << **endl;** I get an "invalid overload of endl"
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not compile, or it will crash when running? Those two are kind of mutually exclusive.

Comment: If it "won't compile", what error message does your compiler give?

Comment: That's a very long sentence...

Comment: "Won't compile" and "crash instantly" seem like 2 incompatible symptoms.  Either it won't compile, or it compiles and crashes instantly when run.

Comment: I fixed the error thing I was not declaring int main()..., but my main question is how can I overload so that I can use the print function as it is there in my main file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operator<<` function is a template function, so note that inside `friend` declaration:

```
friend ostream& operator<< <T>(ostream& is, const Queue<T>& theQ);
```

This is not the as Andy's variant, as Andy's variant allows this:

```
#include <iostream>


template <class T>
class A
{
public:
        A(T d): data(d){}

private:
        // friend is any template instance of function foo, and not just foo<T>!
        template <class U>
        friend void foo(A<U>& t);

        T data;
};


A<int> ai(1);


template <class T>
void foo(A<T>& t)
{
        // A<int> will accept foo<double> as friend
        std::cout << ai.data << std::endl;
        std::cout << t.data << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        A<double> ad(2);
        foo(ad);
        return 0;

}
```

However, in my case, you need to add few forward declarations, in order to make this right:

```
#include <iostream>


// 2. But before that you need to forward-declare your class, so the function
// can know about the class.
template <class T>
class A;


// 1. You need to forward-declare your foo function...
template <class T>
void foo(A<T>& t);


template <class T>
class A
{
public:
        A(T d): data(d){}

private:

        friend void foo<T>(A<T>& t);


        T data;
};


A<int> ai(1);


template <class T>
void foo(A<T>& t)
{
        // error: ‘int A<int>::data’ is private within this context
        //std::cout << ai.data << std::endl;
        std::cout << t.data << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        A<double> ad(2);
        foo(ad);

}
```

Here's your code, but you need more work to do:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Employee{

protected:
    long empId;
    string empName;
    string email;
public:
        Employee(){}
        Employee(long i, string n){
         empName = n,
         empId =i;
         email = "Unknown";
    }
};

class Student{

protected:
    long stId;
    int year;
    string email;
    string schoolName;
public:
    Student(){}
    Student(long i, int y, string sn){
    stId = i;
    year =y;
    email = "Unknown";
    schoolName=sn;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Queue;

template<class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Queue<T>& theQ);


template<class T>
class Queue{
protected:
    vector<T> theQ;
public:
    void Push(T item);
    T pop();
    void ReadAnItem();
    void PrintQ() const;
 friend ostream& operator<< <T> (ostream& is, const Queue<T>& theQ);
};


template<class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Queue<T>& theQ){
        // I will just use this, but it should receive ostream
        theQ.PrintQ();
        return os;
}
template<class T>
void Queue<T>::ReadAnItem(){
    T item;
    cout << "Enter the data please: " << endl;
    cin >> item;
    Push(item);
}

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::Push(T item){
    // this aint gonna work! Use std::deque and push_front! theQ.front() = item;
}

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::PrintQ() const{
    cout << "The content of the array is as follows: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i< theQ.size(); i++){
        // You need to overlload operator<< for student to make this work! cout << theQ[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
        Queue<Student> s;
      s.Push(Student());

        std::cout << s;
        return 0;
}
```

Note - this code is not perfect (nor good), it just shows you how to solve this particular problem. You need to move body of `PrintQ()` method to `operator<<` or to make your `PrintQ` to accept and return `ostream&`. Also, I've already marked it as a `const`, as it doesn't change state of the class. Also, you don't have `operator<<` for student, so you are not able to output it into the `ostream&`. Also, `vector.first() = s` will always wipe your first element (it will copy `s` into the first element of the vector using `operator=`), or it will fail, if there's no first element. I'm sure there's other bugs, but these are only that I saw while trying your program.

**Edit**

For each different class, you need to have different `operator<<`. So, change the `Student` to:

```
class Student{

protected:
    long stId;
    int year;
    string email;
    string schoolName;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s);
public:
    Student(){}
    Student(long i, int y, string sn){
    stId = i;
    year =y;
    email = "Unknown";
    schoolName=sn;
    }
};
```

and add another `operator<<` body:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s)
{
   os << s.stId << s.year << s.email << std::endl;
   return os;
}
```

Also, do this for `Employee`. And you should consider moving common fields from `Student` and `Employee` to base class `Person`.

Comment: this is the same as Andy pointed out right?? just written in different ways?

Comment: thanks man, so as you pointed I need to overload the << operator in every class in order to make it function with each Object? so I would do 

`class Employee;
class Student;
template<class T>
class Queue;

template<class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Queue<T>& theQ);`

at the very top???

Comment: @AndreyArias I am not sure what you mean by that, but see the edit, maybe it will clear things for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare that friend function as a template:

```
template <class U>
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& is, const Queue<U>& theQ);
```

Comment: I am just curious - should this be `const Queue<U>& theQ` or `const Queue<T>& theQ`?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: Technically I believe it doesn't matter in this case, but the later case is much more confusing for me.

Comment: thanks so I add the template <class T> line above the line inside the class Queue as it is? or should I declare it outside?

Comment: @AndreyArias: you need to add it to function declaration inside `Queue`

Comment: I edited my file and I am not sure on what to put inside the overloaded << operator in order to make it work with my Print() function I wrote "os < theQ.Print();"

Comment: @AndreyArias: You don't have `Print()` method and your `PrintQ()` returns `void` so you cannot use it this way. You should remove your `PrintQ()` function and move its implementation to that `operator<<` outputting what you need to `std::ostream`.